# Expose url to webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

In our project we want to query a document management system for a specific document or movie. The dms returns a URL with the document location (for example: http://mydomain.myserver1.share/mypdf.pdf or http://mydomain.myserver2.share/mymovie.avi).

We want to expose the document to internet users and intranet users. The requested file can be large (large video files).

Our architecture is like:

request goes like: webapp1 -> webapp2 -> webapp3 -> dms

response goes like: dms -> webapp3 -> webapp2 -> webapp1

webapp1 could be on the internet.

I have have been thinking how we can obfuscate the real url from the dms, due to security issues. I have seen implementations from other webapps where the pdf URL was obfusicated by creating a temp file for the requested document that is specific for the session and user. So other users cannot easily guess the documentname of other users.

My question: is there a pattern that deals with exposing company/user vulernable data to the public ?

Our development is in C# 3.5.

Comment: In your architecture, is webapp1 calling the dms or just exposing the URI directly?

Comment: Webapp 1 is the original caller, webapp2 is a process service that has a typed, specific contract as input. 

Webapp2 then converts this typed requestschema to a untyped request schema that is exposed by webapp3(with keyvalue pairs). 

Webapp3 is a WCF platform service with the untyped, general key-value schema and is calling the dms and waits for an answer from the dms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to handle it is to create a ashx file (or some other way of creating a URL) and have it serve the pdf.  Since WCF supports REST you could always do it through that too.  Just load the pdf into memory and push the byte contents into the response stream.

Alternatively, you might want to look into these:

http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/

http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Comment: This is not what we want. Pushing the data into memory is a huge load on memory per server, because there are many, many requests in a second and the data must be travelled over many webapps before it is consumed. We want to look for a way how we can safely expose a URL to a caller so no other callers can grab that same data by URL guessing

Comment: To serve the pdf, the server is going to have to load it into memory one way or another.  It has to push it out to the client.  Whether you load into memory, or let IIS do it for you, it has to happen.

Comment: The dms can also expose its internal file location by a url. But we do not want to expose that "internal" location to the public. The WCF service has to make a copy or load the file as byte array... But after that the file must be published again as a new URL location that must be only available by the session that requested it.